# Can textures change between resolutions?

Tags: textures

I'm a beginner in game design and textures have been bothering me. How do they work in video games? Here's what I mean.

Can textures change between resolutions in settings?

Or is it tied to screen resolution? As in your game has 4k textures but the user sets the display to 1080P. And if this is true then what resolution should the textures you put in the game be?

Comment: It's pretty easy to find games that have multiple texture resolution settings in their graphics options, or that let players download optional high-res texture packs. Does that not answer your question, by demonstrating that games can and often do load textures at different resolutions, depending on the player's settings? Do you need help implementing this kind of feature in your game, or is there something else you're snagged on?

Comment: Ohhh so they do add different texture resolutions. How is this implemented? What's it called ? Are there some tutorials? And lastly, wouldn't it be easier to use display resolution instead?

Comment: I think best examples of 'simple ways of doing stuff' are found in games released around 2005 (although for textures, I think even games released nowadays follow the same principes).
They usually shipped with textures at different resolutions so the game could simply load the one needed. If you own such games, you might found them in your game folders.

Comment: Want to edit your question to clarify what you need to know about implementing this in your game? Be sure to be specific about the language/frameworks you're using. You could absolutely use the resolution as a hint for what textures might be best, but two players with the same screen resolution might have vastly different video cards and available video memory, or one might prefer high detail while the other prefers higher framerate, so screen resolution is far from the only relevant consideration.

Comment: Ummm...well idk about what framework I'd use. But c# is the language. Unfortunately when I say beginner. I mean...extremely beginner. As in I've done a few unity tutorials and know the basics of c# and that's it. I was just asking cause I like to plan ahead. I wanted it to be on my list of things to learn how to do. I was hoping it'd have a special name I could just use to look up tutorials for when I'm ready. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @Jojo Don't apologize for asking questions, even if they seem dumb in hindsight (don't worry this is a useful feature to know) it's best to ask them early so you don't have to post a more complicated "why doesn't X do Y and how can I fix it" later. Also it's always good for more experienced programmers to brush up on the basics once in a while so these kinds of questions are perfect for that, although you may want to consider asking them on chat if you want someone to walk you through it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is [mipmaps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap). Mipmaps are a sort of Texture resolution hierarchy that allow you to sample different resolutions as needed. So, yes, games will sample different resolutions as needed for things like antialiasing, hierarchial level of detail settings, texture filtering and overall graphical settings.

Comment: Oh I see so that's what it's called. This will allow me to give the player the option to choose what resolution of textures to use, right?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to go about it. Higher level graphics programmers may suggest a variety of options, such as simply uploading the texture size you need or something like that, but mipmaps are a fairly common way to do it.

Comment: Another nice thing about mipmaps is many game engines often have features for changing texture resolutions automatically if they are certain distances from the player. This helps improve performance by only sending small textures for super far away game objects. A similar feature (although a bit more difficult to use) is LOD (level of detail) meshes which is the same idea except for 3d game objects.

Comment: Would LOD also give the player a choice in changing the character models to a lower poly version for better performance?

Comment: @Jojo LOD can be whatever you’d like it to be. It just means level of detail. Mipmaps are a convenient way to give you options for downsampling, but in many graphics pipelines lower poly models must be uploaded to the GPU separately, as opposed to mipmaps which contain all levels of detail. Tessellation shaders can use level of detail settings to produce less complex geometry at a distance, but in general you will have to design the LOD system to behave however you need it to. Games often do not cookie-cutter solutions, you are allowed to draw outside the lines, so to speak.

Comment: It definitely sounds complicated. I guess I won't understand any of this until I reach that point. I have more questions like can LOD transfer animation to the low poly model or do you have to animate everything twice, one for low poly and one for high poly. But I don't wanna bother you guys considering I'm still a huge beginner